# Gulp Jade Issue

Tags: node.js, express, gulp, pug

I am trying to compile a jade template then feed it into another gulp process for one file but it just seems to skip the last process.. its almost like it wont recognise it because it was created by gulp-jade

heres the section thats causing the issue

```
    gulp.src("src/assets/jade/index.jade")
    .pipe(jade({
      pretty: true
     }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest( 'src/' ))


    gulp.src( 'src/index.html' )
        .pipe(useref())       
        .pipe(gulpif('assets/lib.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', cssnano()))
        .pipe(gulpif('!*.html', rev()))
        .pipe(revReplace())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(public/))
        .on('finish', done);
```

so  the first gulp source gets the jade file and makes it into a html file then the next one gets that new html file and processes it but it doesnt seem to get to this stage and there is no errors

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could be causing the issue is that you're missing quotes around the destination path in your 2nd gulp.dest() call:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest(public/))
```

Should be:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('public/'))
```